# How do I POST form data from bootstrap modal to backend?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap-3, .net-core

I have a login and registration form that works properly when used on a regular View, however, when I place that form into a modal (Bootstrap v3) it fails to post the data (the debugger shows all the fields to be null upon submit).

```
   @model myNamespace.Models.AllUserViewModels
    <div class="container">
  <div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"      keyboard="true" aria-labelledby="LoginModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4>Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form asp-controller="User" asp-action="LoginSubmit" method="post" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Log.Email">Email</label>
            <input asp-for="Log.Email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" id="Email"> 
            <span asp-validation-for="Log.Email"></span>


            <label asp-for="Log.Password">Password</label>
            <input asp-for="Log.Password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" id="Password"> 
            <span asp-validation-for="Log.Password"></span>

            <span>@ViewBag.loginError</span>

            <br>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <!--End Login Modal -->
```

EDIT
The reason my form was not posting to my controller was due to my having forgotten to add the "POST" verb in my controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. The reason that my data was not passing through to my backend was because in my controller I forgot to change the name of the View Model that I was using as a parameter to my method as well as forgetting to change the references to my model when attempting to do db calls, password verification, et cetera...

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("LoginSubmit")]
        public IActionResult LoginSubmit(AllUserViewModels model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    // If there are no errors upon form submit check db for proper creds.
                    User LoggedUser = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Log.Email);
                    var Hasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();
                    // Check    hashed password.
                    if (Hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(LoggedUser, LoggedUser.Password, model.Log.Password) != 0)
                    {
                        // Set user id in session for use in identification, future db calls, and for greeting the user.
                        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("LoggedUserId", LoggedUser.Id);

                        return RedirectToAction("Account");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.loginError = "Sorry, your password was incorrect.";
                        return View("landing");
                    }
                }
                // If no proper creds redirect to login page and return error.
                catch
                {
                    ViewBag.loginError = "Sorry, your email or password were incorrect.";
                    return View("landing");
                }
            }
            // If form submit was illegal redirect to login and display model validation errors.
            else
            {
                return View("landing");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms), the `asp-for` tag helper generates the `id` and `name` attributes already.

> Generates the id and name HTML attributes for the expression name
>   specified in the asp-for attribute.

So, you should remove the id attributes on inputs.

```
<input asp-for="Log.Password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I knew that was the case regarding names but I wasn't aware it also did that for id's.

Comment: This was useful information but did not solve the problem regarding the POST data not being passed to the backend. I solved the problem and wrote it up. The problem was in my controller, which I didn't post since I did not think it was related to this issue. Sorry about that.